# How to translate URL in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, url, translate

I read severals post here to translate the **"customer/account"** with something else.

I have no idea how to do this for the **"controller"** account.
I mean, If I change `routes.xml` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customer" frontName="client">
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The **"customer"** part of the url will be translated to **"client"** (french word).

But, what's about **"account"** ?
I tried with marketing / seo admin backoffice, without success.

Answer (score 0):

For Front Route - front name is used from routes.xml file for any module.

Here as you wanted to change account and login URl - so you need to make a one directory in Controller folder of Customer Module.

Exact location is **Controller/Account/Login.php**

Here frontname is **customer** for any action of customer.

Then You need to customize for display specific action in url.

**For customer/account - Customer is Frontname and Account is Account Directory under the Controller/Account**

**Same as for Customer/Account/Login - Here directory is Controller/Account/Login.php**

If we do not pass third parameter then by default it takes index.php